# Force TeamCity To Only Checkout The Code I Need (Checkout From Multiple Places) Using svn --depth

Tags: svn, teamcity, depth, svn-checkout

I have an old svn repository with 4+GB of source for trunk.  I'd only like to pull my lib directory, my main project directory, and maybe one or two dependent directories.  I know if I were checking out the things I need, I could be selective in what I want to pull down.  However, I'm using TeamCity to talk to my SVN server.  I want it to just pull down what it needs to build while maintaining the right directory structure, build, and that's it.  Does anyone know if TeamCity can make use of svn checkout --depth?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [VCS Checkout Rules](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/VCS+Checkout+Rules#). For example, if you were to check out only lib directory you could use.

```
-:.
+:lib
```

The first line will exclude root dir and the second line will check out lib. You may need to modify the path of lib depending upon its location in SVN and your VCS checkout url. Check [Configuring VCS Roots](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Roots) for more information.